# How to find Last record in group

Tags: sql, inner-join, inner-query

Below is my data table:

```
+----------+--------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------------+--------+
| RegionID | ReceivedDate | FdNo   | FmNo  | FromRegionID  | ToRegionID  | HFlag  |
+----------+--------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------------+--------+
| 26       | 2014-04-10   | 104152 | 1     | 26            | 27          | 1      |
| 26       | 2014-04-10   | 104152 | 1     | 27            | 26          | 0      |
| 26       | 2014-04-10   | 104152 | 2     | 26            | 27          | 1      |
| 26       | 2014-04-10   | 104152 | 2     | 27            | 26          | 0      |
| 26       | 2014-04-10   | 104152 | 3     | 26            | 27          | 1      |
| 26       | 2014-04-10   | 104152 | 3     | 27            | 26          | 0      |
| 26       | 2014-04-10   | 104152 | 4     | 26            | 27          | 1      |
| 26       | 2014-04-10   | 104152 | 4     | 27            | 26          | 0      |
+----------+--------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------------+--------+
```

I want to select last record from each group of fdNo.In sample table I have given the data with duplicate count of 2 ,in real case it might be 3,4, so on.

expected output :

```
+----+-------------------------+--------+---+----+----+---+
| 26 | 2014-04-10 15:35:30.000 | 104152 | 1 | 27 | 26 | 0 |
| 26 | 2014-04-10 15:35:30.000 | 104152 | 2 | 27 | 26 | 0 |
| 26 | 2014-04-10 15:35:44.000 | 104152 | 3 | 27 | 26 | 0 |
| 26 | 2014-04-10 15:35:44.000 | 104152 | 4 | 27 | 26 | 0 |
+----+-------------------------+--------+---+----+----+---+
```

I want to append the Ans Query to my Origininal Query (from which the actual table is brougt)

Raw Query  :

```
SELECT tblreceipt.regionid, 
       tblreceipt.receiveddate, 
       tblreceipt.folderno, 
       tblreceipt.formno, 
       tbltransite.dispatchfromregionid, 
       tbltransite.dispatchtoregionid, 
       tbltransite.horeceivedflag 
FROM   tblreceipt 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbltransite 
                    ON tblreceipt.folderno = tbltransite.folderno 
WHERE  tblreceipt.folderno = 104152
```

Comment: can you format your table structure , it is difficult to read

Comment: ok I wll try .. am new on sof.

Comment: Last based on what? Date, some primary key. In general you can use row_number() over() for this kind of query.

Comment: if you provide what output you are expecting , other member can help you better

Comment: last record of 104152 and 1 combination like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With CTE As (
select  tblReceipt.RegionID,
        tblReceipt.ReceivedDate, 
        tblReceipt.FolderNo,
        tblReceipt.FormNo,
        tblTransite.DispatchFromRegionID,
        tblTransite.DispatchToRegionID,
        tblTransite.HOReceivedFlag,
        Row_Number() Over(Order By FmNo, HFlag) A Rn
        from     tblReceipt
                      left outer join
                 tblTransite
                      on tblReceipt.FolderNo = tblTransite.FolderNo
        where    tblReceipt.FolderNo = 104152
        )
        Select Top 1 From CTE Order By Rn Desc
```

Comment: No @meysam tolouee , Its not expected 
it showon 1 record only,Am expecting 100 records if my table contain 200 recors

Comment: Where rn = 1, not select top 1 ... order by?

Comment: I made inner join with cte for max of RN and it worked
select *  From CTE c1 inner join (
            select MAX(Rn)  as Rn
            from CTE 
            group by FolderNo,FormNo
           ) c2  On c1.Rn = c2.Rn
           order by c1.FolderNo,c1.FormNo